# Resetting state of transition after the transition played

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a message which I display on the screen when a user clicks on some links. I use a transition on the opacity to get the message to fade away.

The problem is that when a user clicks on the next link which is supposed to display the message, the element has its opacity set to 0 (thus it's not visible).

The opacity transition is triggered by a JavaScript function.

My question: would it be possible to reset the opacity (back to 1) before the transition effect happens?

I only see a nasty way such as triggering a function from within the function that triggers the opacity transition, to reset the opacity back to 1. Something like:

```
setTimeout(function(){elem.style.opacity = 1;)}, 3000);
```

But this is not great because I'd like the opacity to be reset as soon as a user clicks another link for which this message is displayed.

ideas?

## EDIT:

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/1umdrmqb/1/)

HTML:

```
<div id="pop_up" class="pop_up">negative</div>

<a class="something_else" href="#" onclick="show(event, this); return false;">toto</a>
<a class="something_else" href="#" onclick="show(event, this); return false;">titi</a>
```

CSS:

```
.pop_up
{
     position: absolute:
     top: -10px;
     padding: 10px;
     background-color: orange;
     opacity: 1;
     transition: opacity 1s linear;
}
```

JS:

```
function show(e, elem)
{
    msg = document.getElementById("pop_up");
    msg.style.top = elem.offsetTop;
    msg.style.left = elem.offsetLeft;
    msg.style.opacity = 0;
    msg.innerHTML = "Hug Me!";
}
```

Comment: Just reset the opacity in the event handler.

Comment: Sounds like a good idea, but would you be kind enough to develop a bit. I will try to find out on my own, but some code would help me a lot.

Comment: Can you add a simple version of the code you have?  maybe create a fiddle?  much easier to both understand and explain with an example

Comment: @Adam: tried to create a fiddle but can't get it to work. just added the code. it's pretty small.

Comment: @user18490 I fixed the fiddle. The problem was that the `show` function was declared in the `load` event handler, thus wasn't global. Moreover, you should avoid adding inline event handlers and global variables. See http://jsfiddle.net/1umdrmqb/7/

Comment: @Oriol. Thank you I am new to fiddle. Like it a lot but don't understand it very well yet. Thanks for fixing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I know what you want.  You need to reset the transition to none and back again each time, and also reset the opacity each time and hide/show.  Using the following CSS:

```
.pop_up
{
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: orange;
}
```

and the following javascript:

```
function show(e, elem) {
    var msg = document.getElementById("pop_up");   
    msg.style.transition = 'none';
    msg.style.display = 'none';
    msg.style.opacity = 100;
    msg.innerHTML = "Hug Me!";    
    msg.style.display = 'block';
    msg.style.top = '' + elem.offsetTop + 'px';
    msg.style.left = '' + elem.offsetLeft + 'px';
    msg.style.transition = 'opacity 2s linear';    
    msg.style.opacity = 0;        
}
```

I think you get the effect you want.  I have changed to a 2s transition to see ity better, that you can adjust.  The point is to hide and reset the popup each time, then reset the transition and show so that the transition runs again.

I have made msg a local vairable (with the `var`declaration) but also agree with the comments that using global functions and inline event handlers like this is not ideal.  Improvments to that depnd on if you want to use a js library and if so which or if you want to stick to pure js.

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/adamconway/xzug0qap/9/) (only tested in Firefox).

This technique stopped working with me, until I nailed done what actually make it work. It's necessary to keep this line in the JS code:

```
msg.style.bottom = elem.offsetTop + 'px';
```

If you remove it, it seems like the CSS for the element is not re-evaluated, which means the transition is actually not reset from 'none' to 'opacity 1s ease' for instance, which actually triggers the transition. So, if you remove the lines that actually reset the position of the div, the css won't be re-evaluated. In my case, I ended up needing the element to have a fixed position. So I first do:

```
msg.style.bottom = elem.offsetTop + 'px';
```

Immediately followed by:

```
msg.style.bottom = 0;
```

The first call internally forces the transition to be reset from none to something else, and then of course I finally positioned the element where I want.

Note that the first line might as well be:

```
var tmp = elem.offsetTop;
```

What's important here, is to change the state of the element, so that its CSS is being internally re-evaluated by the browser engine.

Comment: Absolutely brillant. You saved my day. Thank you so much. It's frustrating because I tried that before and couldn't get it to work so must have done things in the wrong order. This is very cool.  I was also experimenting with addEventListener and transitionEnd as suggested by Oriol but it can only reset values when the animation is finished. So not ideal. Thx again.